# Matrix Math: Using coefficients from a linear regression to calculate values

Tags: r, math, matrix

I have a matrix[D] consisting of 1 row and 2 columns (intercept in column 1, slope in column 2).

I then have a matrix[C] of 30 rows and 2 columns, in which column 2 of this matrix is of interest.  I want to take  the slope[D, 2] value and multiply it by [C, 2] values and add the intercept [D,1], and then store the newly calculated values in a new matrix.

My code as of now:

```
A <- matrix(c(Box.Z, Box.DC.gm), nrow=42)
```

randco <- function(A) {

```
B<- A[sample(42,6),]
arows <- apply(A, 1, paste, collapse="_")
brows <- apply(B, 1, paste, collapse="_")
C<- A[-match(brows, arows), ]
D<- lm(B[,2] ~ B[,1])$coefficients
```

}

Z <- t(replicate(10000, randco(A)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `predict` on your `lm` object. The trick is to give it C with the columns reversed:

```
predict(lm(B[,2]~B[,1]), newdata=list(B=C[,2:1]))
```

Comment: If I want the newdata to be in a matrix instead of a list, is that possible?

Comment: If upon coercion to a dataframe (which will be attempted) the resultant dataframe has the necessary column names, then predict will not throw an error. Whether the overall stategy makes sense is your responsibility

Comment: Can you explain what the list(B=C[,2:1]) part of the syntax. I am not sure what they are referring to here. Thanks!

Comment: Because you specified that the explanatory variable in the lm call is the second column of an object named `B`, that is what you must pass to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column of 1's to your C matrix, and the matrix multiply:

```
cbind(1,C[,2]) %*% D
```

Comment: I want to multiply my column 2 of matrix C by only the slope in column 2 of matrix D, and then add the intercept value in column 1 of matrix D. Your function doesn't seem to do that.